# CPU or GPU bound? profiling OpenGL application

Tags: language-agnostic, opengl, profiling, gpu

I've got an OpenGL application which I'm afraid is GPU bound.

How can I be sure that's the case?
And if it is, how can I profile the code run by the GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows, Linux or Mac, (well, a computer!)  give a try to [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/).

Comment: From the page you linked it looks like it also supports Linux and OS X.

Comment: No longer supports OSX...  for quite a while now.

Answer (score 2):

I would also check it with [AMD GPU PerfStudio](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/PerfStudio/Pages/default.aspx).

It will analyse your GPU and CPU usage and show relative load values.

Comment: Link broken. Try here (note: Linux and Windows only.. Sadly no mac version):
http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-perfstudio/

Answer (score 1):

If your OpenGL thread should uses less than one core you are not CPU bound. If you're running at 60Hz you're probably limited by vsync.

Answer (score 0):

gDEBugger no longer supports OSX..
For OSX users (and perhaps other OS's) the Intel Graphics Performance Analyser might be worth a look

https://software.intel.com/en-us/gpa

Info [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/gpa/15.1/osx/)